# label too long in yAxis with chartJs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I have a problem with labels too long on the Y axis with the module "chartjs" and "vuejs". I posted an image to illustrate the problem:

[image: Example image showing y-axis label truncated]

My code:

```
<bar-chart
  :max="100"
  :xlabels="50"
  suffix="%"
  :dataset="{hoverBorderWidth: 10}"
  v-if="charts=='bar'"
  :data="data.percentsData"
  :colors="['#01E3AD']"
  :style="calcHeight(data.percentsData.length)"
  :download="survey_name + ' - ' +data.title"
  >
</bar-chart>
```

Comment: What is your actual question/ expected result ? Because my actual answer would be: your label is too long, make it shorter, and enforce a limit so that nobody can ever enter a so long label.

Comment: it's not possible because it's a question.I have clients who want to read this whole question. if I write a line break \ n or <br> it's written as a text and not written as a code

Comment: there is nothing you can do, you should truncate the label or only display the chart in screen wide enough to be able to display all

Comment: I would like to write a new line but it does not work side server with laravel.with a function `$this->cutString($proposition->entitled,0,70),$resultCount[$question->id][$proposition->id]]`

Answer (score 3):

You can break the string over multiple lines. This is done by splitting the string into an array. Chart.js parses each array element as a single line.

Example:

```js
let labels = [
    ['this is a very long label', 'broken across two lines'],
    'short label'
  ],
  myBarChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Series1',
        data: [1, 1]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
  });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```